# how to convert n-hot vectors to multi-labels in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a multi-classification task, and I have gotten the n-hot type predictions like

```
n_hot_prediction = [[0, 1, 1],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [1, 0, 1]]
```

and another top_k array like

```
top_k_prediction = [[1, 2],
                    [0, 1],
                    [0, 1]]
```

Firstly, I wish to get a function which works like:

```
tf.function1(n_hot_prediction)  #output: [[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]]
```

Secondly, I with to find another function which works like:

```
tf.function2(top_k_prediction) #output: [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Are there any functions or methods that works like tf.function1 and tf.function2?

Comment: Could you clarify the inputs and outputs ?, as the input is not one hot encoded matrix and output is not a labels (index)  nor values `# output: [[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]]`

Comment: for one hot encoding `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(....)` for decoder `tf.math.argmax(...)` or `tf.keras.backend.argmax(....)`

Comment: @m-zayan it's not one-hot but n-hot. For function1, the input is [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]] and output is [[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]] (each row of the output is the index of the elements which equal to 1 in each line of the input). For function2, the input is [[1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]] and the output is [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]] (each row is a 1*n array. The elements at the corresponding index to the input row is 1 and the others are 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second function is pretty simple to implement:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def multi_hot(x, depth=None):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    if depth is None:
        depth = tf.math.reduce_max(x) + 1
    r = tf.range(tf.dtypes.cast(depth, x.dtype))
    eq = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), r)
    return tf.cast(tf.reduce_any(eq, axis=-2), x.dtype)

x = [[1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
tf.print(multi_hot(x))
# [[0 1 1]
#  [1 1 0]
#  [1 1 0]]
```

For the first one, the result is not a proper tensor, so you can make a ragged tensor instead, masking a tensor of sequential values:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def as_labels(x):
    mask = tf.dtypes.cast(x, tf.bool)
    s = tf.shape(mask)
    r = tf.reshape(tf.range(s[-1]), tf.concat([tf.ones(tf.rank(x) - 1, tf.int32), [-1]], axis=0))
    r = tf.tile(r, tf.concat([s[:-1], [1]], axis=0))
    return tf.ragged.boolean_mask(r, mask)

x = [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
print(as_labels(x).to_list())
# [[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]]
```